# Intel driver update utility does not recognize Intel(R) display audio

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers, updates

I understand when the utility does not recognize other pieces of hardware such as Realtek, but it should be able to detect the driver of its own brand. How do I fix problem? The sound works most of the time, but sometimes, the audio randomly mutes and cannot produce sound again until a restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the drivers directly from intel. Worked for me, for my coreHT. http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect